# How to effectively process million records using JavaSpark

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to JavaSpark
I came into a requirement to compare and process millions of records, i used plain java multi threading but want to do in spark way, to increase performance

Problem Statement:
There are millions of records in our database,i need to compare it with another List and process it.
Example:
Step 1 : We have a List1 with million strings fetched from filesystem (this doesnt have an issue).
Step 2 : We are getting another million records from database and adding to List2.
Step 3 : iterate and compare List1 elements with List2 (if List1 element exist in List2 , update List2 element in database)
**The challenge**
Step 2 and Step 3 taking lot of time,how to convert this problem statement into JavaSpark way to increase performance.

What I have tried?

```
List paths (this contains million strings)
Iterator<T> oneMillionRecords =
        database.fetching();// this is taking time
                Iterable<T> iterable = () -> oneMillionRecords;
JavaRDD<T> parentPathRDDs = javaSparkContext.parallelize(
              StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()));

List<T> avaliableResources = parentPathRDDs.filter(r -> {
    return paths.contains(r.getPath()));
}).map(dr->{dr.setXXX("YYY"); return dr;}).collect();

List<T> unreachableResources = parentPathRDDs.filter(r -> {
    return (!paths.contains(r.getPath())));
}).map(dr->{dr.setX("ZZZ"); return dr;}).collect();

List<T> allRes = new ArrayList<>();
allRes.addAll(avaliableResources);
allRes.addAll(unreachableResources);
resourcesToUpdate.addAll(allRes);
```

The above code didn't make much impact on performance, can anyone please suggest better solution?

Comment: You should definitely create `parentPathRDDs` by making Spark read directly from your database. And maybe there are other `filter` you're running in code that could be performed in the database already.

Comment: paths have millions of records, cant send in query to perform that in database (as i am checking each row element contains in paths or not)

Comment: IMO, the main gain is to make `parentPathRDDs` by reading with Spark. And regarding `paths`, you're probably doing something wrong if you're calling `.contains` on a 1M-element list. The first thing I'd change about this is to make `paths` an RDD too and perform an inner join. If you can't do that, then at least use a `HashSet` instead of a (any) `List`.

Comment: You don't need either of the lists. You can do step 3 with an UPDATE statement per element of the input file.

Comment: In addition, if the string is the database primary, you may get good speedup by processing the updates in batches in key order.

Comment: @user207421 How can i do step 3 , without comparing, can you please elaborate for better understanding

Comment: Get the database to do the comparing. `UPDATE table SET column = value[, ...] WHERE ...`.